# Create JAR from Eclipse Project

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, jar, osmdroid

I'm trying to build this project https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/Osmdroid-Plus/wiki to a JAR but I can't. I followed the "Configuration" steps in there and alredy have the Tomcat ant command to build, but it says "build.xml does not exist!" and ant -v command doesn't work either or creating a build with eclipse. I export it as jar with eclipse but using that JAR gives me an error in my project "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1".

Answer (score 0):

have you try this? :

```
Right click on project -> export -> select under "java" -> select path -> finish
```

this step would create a jar file for your project.

to use the jar into another project:

```
Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Add external archive -> select the jar file
```